# How to create ssh tunnel to dockerfile/mysql container

Tags: mysql, macos, ssh, docker

I am looking for the right syntax to use to create an SSH tunnel (on a non-standard port, eg 3309) that I can use from Mac OS X Yosemite terminal, which will enable me to use Sequel Pro to connect to the mysql container running inside boot2docker.

For example, I tried this,

```
ssh -L3309:localhost:3306 docker@$(boot2docker ip)
```

but it asks for docker@192.168.59.103's password and I don't think that is needed so I'm assuming that's not quite right.

Thanks!

Comment: What specifically is still asking for a password? ssh? Or Sequel?

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to tunnel into docker, you can just setup a ssh connection through Sequel pro

Create a new connection in Sequel pro and choose the SSH connection option and follow the instructions below to populate the fields.

#### Mysql Host:

Issue the command below to get your mysql host

```
docker inspect --format='{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}' "container id or container name"
```

If you don't know your container id or name, do `docker ps -a`, and locate the id or name from the output.

#### Username, password, database (the db credentials)

#### SSH Host

Enter `boot2docker ip` in your terminal to get the host

#### SSH User

docker

#### SSH Password

tcuser

Test your connection and after it is successful, save it to your favorites!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you are looking for you, but the docker password is *tcuser* (the standard default) which gets you into the boot2docker host.